# How to return a generic ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Sorry didnt know who to formulate the question best, but i will try to explain my Problem here, i have following class:

```
public class ReadOnlyTable<T extends Model> implements ReadOnly<T> {
...

protected ReadOnlyTable() {
    initTable();
}

protected void reloadDataSource() {
    initTable();
}

...

@Override
public ArrayList<T> findAll() {
    ArrayList<T> result = null;

    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = datasource.getAllEntries();
        //  // Logger.getLogger().write("FindAllQuery time was " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Lets say T is class "Galaxy", then i tried to loop over all elements in the returned Array, with following Code

```
    for (Galaxy gal : gDAO.findAll()) {

    }
```

Why does it give me an error that Galaxy is required, but Object is found?? What am i doing wrong, that i have return type ArrayList and not ArrayList<T>

**EDIT 1:**

gDAO is defined this way

```
private static GalaxyDAO gDAO = (GalaxyDAO) DAOFactory.get(GalaxyDAO.class);
```

And DAOFactory looks like this

```
    public static <T> T get(Class clazz) {
    if (!instanceList.containsKey(clazz)) {
        try {

            GenericDAO genericDAO = null;
            Constructor constructor;
            constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            genericDAO = (GenericDAO) constructor.newInstance();
            instanceList.put(clazz, genericDAO);

            return (T)genericDAO;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            DebugBuffer.writeStackTrace(DAOFactory.class.getName(), ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            DebugBuffer.writeStackTrace(DAOFactory.class.getName(), ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            DebugBuffer.writeStackTrace(DAOFactory.class.getName(), ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            DebugBuffer.writeStackTrace(DAOFactory.class.getName(), ex);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            DebugBuffer.writeStackTrace(DAOFactory.class.getName(), ex);
        }
    }else{
        return (T)instanceList.get(clazz);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and finally

```
public class GalaxyDAO extends ReadWriteTable<Galaxy> implements GenericDAO {
```

and yeah .. ReadWriteTable extends ReadOnlyTable

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable implements ReadWrite<T> {
public ReadWriteTable() {              
    super();
}
```

**Appendix to acknowledged solution**

I had a mistake in my inferfaces which prevented to give the Type to ReadOnlyTable see

```
public interface ReadWrite<T> extends ReadOnly {
```

instead of

```
public interface ReadWrite<T> extends ReadOnly<T> {
```

after fixing that i could also change following line

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable<T> implements ReadWrite<T> {
```

Comment: Can you show the code that declares `gDAO`?

Comment: can you put some code here? looks like you not creating ReadOnlyTable properly, you should create it like this: new ReadOnlyTable<Galaxy>() and it'll work.

Comment: Could it be that your datasource returns a List of type Object and not of type Galaxy?

Comment: I dont think the datasource is the Problem, cause functions in ReadWriteTable return a correctly typed ArrayList

Comment: Ok, this is too many different bits of code.  It would be much easier to debug this if you can boil this all down to a [*minimal* test-case](http://sscce.org), i.e. the shortest complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I updated my post, please check it.

Comment: Datasource returns:  

    @Override
    public ArrayList<T> getAllEntries() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gDAO` is an instance of your class `ReadOnlyTable<T extends Model>` ? What is it's type parameter (how did you declare it)?

It has to be `Galaxy`, otherwise it will not work.

Update: Now that you posted more code, the problem is that you have to pass the type parameter `Galaxy` to the class `ReadOnlyTable<T extends Model>`, where the `findAll` method is, otherwise it doesn't know what T is, and will return `ArrayList<Object>`.

This line is the problem:

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable implements ReadWrite<T>
```

The class ReadOnlyTable also has to receive the type parameter:

```
ReadOnlyTable<T extends Model>
```

So the line has to be:

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable<T extends Model> implements ReadWrite<T>
```

Comment: public class GalaxyDAO extends ReadWriteTable<Galaxy> implements GenericDAO {

here Galaxy is defined for ReadWriteTable shouldnt that be enough?

Comment: Thank you very much .. i checked the ReadWrite Interface which extended the ReadOnly interface there the generic type was missing, after i fixed that .. i could also add the generic type to the extension to ReadOnlyTable (which impements ReadOnly interface)

Comment: I edited a more detailed explanation of the error to my question .. thanks for leading me to the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ReadWriteTable` declaration, you've declared it as

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable implements ReadWrite<T>
```

extending the raw type `ReadOnlyTable` rather than the parameterized `ReadOnlyTable<T>`.  Change it to

```
public abstract class ReadWriteTable<T extends Model> extends ReadOnlyTable<T> implements ReadWrite<T>
```

Comment: thanks you are right as well would approve your solution as well, but lxx was faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the you declare GalaxyDAO as a row type, it should be declared like that:

```
public class GalaxyDAO<Galaxy> extends ReadWriteTable<Galaxy> implements GenericDAO
```

I'm suer that you got a compiler warning on it, don't ignore warning, you should threat them almost like errors!

Comment: maybe i should do this from time to time >> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.